# One way relationship in Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I need to figure out a way to do a one way relationship in Ember Data. Up until now, I've just put the relationship in only one model, and that's worked well. The problem is that model A becomes dirty when model B is deleted, even though model A has absolutely no concept of model B. How can I have model B point to model A, and make it so that A completely ignores the relationship? I don't mind declaring the relationship in class A to have the proper inverse, I just don't want models of type A to become dirty when that relationship changes.

Also, just FYI, I'm using a rather old version of Ember. I'm using Ember.js RC7 and the Ember Data build from August 26th. And before you ask, no, I am not upgrading.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After searching for several hours, I finally found an answer in the source code of Ember Data. I found this little snippet:

```
DS.OneToManyChange = {};
DS.OneToNoneChange = {};
DS.ManyToNoneChange = {};
DS.OneToOneChange = {};
DS.ManyToManyChange = {};
```

I then did a bit more browsing and found that one-to-none and many-to-none relationships are defined by explicitly making the inverse null. So this little line did the trick:

```
owner: DS.belongsTo('A', { inverse: null })
```

Comment: Wow. This helped me a lot! I had a many-to-one relationship that was only defined as `my-...` on the many side. Say like a `Post` has many comments and a `Comment` has one post that it belongsTo. I do not define the many comments (I never want to get all comments from a Post) but instead define `myComment` as a belongsTo relationship to comment depicting the currentUser's comment on the post. Without an explicit null inverse Ember will incorrectly match this to the belongsTo on `Comments`!